# Like excel Mround function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to round a decimal number to nearest fraction number which end with 0 or 5 in Javascript.example if value is 543.55 should return 545 and if value is 541.99 should return 540.
i tried with Math.round() 
but not able to achieve.
kindly suggest me how to achieve that.
Thanks in advance,
Bijay

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Math.round does the job with a little more extra work. Divide by 5, round it, multiply it back by 5. It is a method I used quite a bit in the past. Here is a simple snippet to show it is working.

```js
function RoundTo(number, roundto){
  return roundto * Math.round(number/roundto);
}

alert(RoundTo(543.55, 5));
alert(RoundTo(541.99, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Ozan. it worked i just used Math.round((Monthly_salary * 0.25)/5)*5